# EF Core dirty check before save entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

If I want to update a `Book` entity in DB with EF core code like this

```
using (var db = new MyContextDB())
{
    var bookEntity = db.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == 123);
    if (result != null)
    {
        bookEntity.Title = "Get rich in 10 days for dummies";
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My question is, if the bookEntity's title is "Get rich in 10 days for dummies" before update. Will EF core skip the update or it will issue update regardless?

Thanks.

Comment: SaveChanges just commits transactions. It seems like you are querying the book entity from the db which would add it to the changetracker. Updating the title "should" be caught within the change tracker and commited on save changes. Give it a test but your code seems like it should work.

Comment: Example change tracker usage similar to your code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is, if the bookEntity's title is "Get rich in 10 days for
> dummies" before update. Will EF core skip the update or it will issue
> update regardless?

No, it will not.

EF issues SQL command for an entity based on its state. For an entity with `Unchanged` state EF doesn't issues any SQL command.

When you fetched the `bookEntity` from database EF started tracking it with `Unchanged` state, and it knows what are the values in database for each property of this entity. If you modify any property, EF will mark the entity as `Modified`, and issue an update command on next `SaveChanges()` call. But if you set the already existing value to a property, you really didn't modify the entity. Therefore, the entity state remains `Unchanged` and EF will not issue any update for that.

You can check the entity state with following code -

```cs
using (var db = new MyContextDB())
{
    var bookEntity = db.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == 123);
    if (result != null)
    {
        var stateBefore = db.Entry(bookEntity).State;  // state is "Unchanged"
        
        bookEntity.Title = "Get rich in 10 days for dummies";
        
        var stateAfter = db.Entry(bookEntity).State;  // state is sill "Unchanged"
        
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

EF core will skip the update. If you want to save changes you can use this syntax for example:

```
using (var db = new MyContextDB())
{
    var bookEntity = db.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == 123);
    if (bookEntity != null)
    {
        bookEntity.Title = "Get rich in 10 days for dummies";
        db.Entry(bookEntity).Property(i=> i.Title).IsModified = true; 
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not true.  Check  -  learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking  from the question @Zakk Diaz comment

Comment: I think the question was, if `db.Entry(bookEntity).Property(i=> i.Title).IsModified = true;` is the default behavior, which is not, when the value is the same.

Comment: OP asked whether EF will issue/submit an update for the entity in the given scenario, _not_ how to update it.

Answer (score 1):

> if the bookEntity's title is "Get rich in 10 days for dummies" before update. Will EF core skip the update or it will issue update regardless?

No, Entity Framework uses an ChangeTracker internaly.

So if you assign the exact same value to the entity again, it will not issue an update query for this property.

To override this behaviour, you need to explict set it, as [Sergey already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66464233/2441442).

```
db.Entry(bookEntity).Property(i=> i.Title).IsModified = true;
```